# SQL Left Join losing rows after filtering

Tags: sql, left-join

I have a multi-table join (only two shown in example) where I need to retain all rows from the base table.  Obviously I use a LEFT JOIN to include all rows on the base table. Without the WHERE clause it works great – When a row doesn’t exist in the Right table the row from the Left table still shows, just with a 0 from the column in the Right table.  The first two rows in the dataset are Labels from the Left table and Count of rows from the Right table, grouped by Label.   All I want is a count of 0 when a label does not have a value from Table2 assigned.

**Table1**

```
Label | FK
----------
Blue  | 1
Red   | 2
Green | 3
```

**Table2**

```
Values | pk    | Date
---------------------------
Dog    | 1     | 02/02/2010
Cat    | 2     | 02/02/2010
Dog    | 1     | 02/02/2010
Cat    | 2     | 02/02/2010
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT 1.Label, COUNT(2.values)
FROM Table1 1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 2 ON 1.fk = 2.pk
GROUP BY 1.Label
```

Good Result Set - No filters

```
Blue  | 2
Red   | 2
Green | 0
```

Great!

My issue is that when I add filtering criteria to remove rows from the Right table the row is removed for my Left join rows (zeroing them out), the Left rows are dropped.  I need the Left rows to remain even if their count is filtered down to zero.

```
SELECT 1.Label, COUNT(2.values)
FROM Table1 1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 2 ON 1.fk = 1.pk
WHERE 2.Date BETWEEN '1/1/2010' AND '12/31/2010'    
GROUP BY 1.Label
```

Bummer Result Set - After Filters

```
Blue | 2
Red  | 2
```

Dukes!

So, what the hell? Do I need to get a temp table with the filtered dataset THEN join it to the Left table? What am I missing?
Thanks!

Do a second join or recursive join.  Get my “good” join table, get a second “filtered” table, then LEFT JOIN them

Comment: Move your where filter to the join, so you will add `AND 2.Date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are filtering on the second table in the `where`.  The values could be `NULL` and `NULL` fails the comparisons.

Move the `where` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT 1.Label, COUNT(2.values)
FROM Table1 1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 2
     ON 1.fk = 1.pk AND
        2.Date BETWEEN 1/1/2010 AND 12/31/2010    
GROUP BY 1.Label
```

Note:

The date formats retain the dates from the question.  However, I don't advocate using `BETWEEN` for dates and the conditions should use standard date formats:

```
SELECT 1.Label, COUNT(2.values)
FROM Table1 1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 2
     ON 1.fk = 1.pk AND
        2.Date >= '2010-01-01' AND
        2.Date < '2011-01-01'
GROUP BY 1.Label;
```

Some databases support the SQL Standard keyword `DATE` to identify date constants.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I had a few of my filters in the join, but not all of them.  Now that I moved all Table2 filters to the JOIN it works great.

Answer (score 4):

simply move the condition in `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

```
LEFT JOIN Table2 2 ON 1.fk = 1.pk AND 2.Date BETWEEN '1/1/2010' AND '12/31/2010'
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all i don't think it is a good idea to have number as an alias. Use a character or a word instead.

I would put the criteria in the join.

```
SELECT T1.Label, COUNT(T2.values)
FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.fk = T1.pk
    AND T2.Date BETWEEN '20100101' AND '20101231'    
GROUP BY T1.Label
```

Other comments:

1. I would use ANSI(yyyyMMdd) format for the dates, so there is no missunderstanding.
2. I would be aware of the BETWEEN as it is not clear what you want to do if the date is '20101231 01:00' Would you like to include that date or not? >= and <= or >= and < is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, put single quotes around the dates. If not, then it will evaluate the expression instead of the date.

```
BETWEEN '1/1/2010' AND '12/31/2010'
```