# Rows are eliminated from LEFT JOIN when using OR in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I've run into a problem with an SQL script that I can't explain with my understanding of LEFT JOINs. I've actually identified and fixed the issue but wanted to understand why the Broken Join version below does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE #LeftTable
(RunID BIGINT,PolicyRef NVARCHAR(MAX),Val NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #LeftTable
VALUES (100,'pol1','hi'),(100,'pol2','hi2'),(100,'pol3','hi3')

CREATE TABLE #RightTable
(RunID BIGINT,PolicyRef NVARCHAR(MAX),Assured NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #RightTable
VALUES (80,'pol1','celec'),(90,'pol2','colorado'),(100,'pol2','colorado')

--SELECT * FROM #LeftTable
--SELECT * FROM #RightTable

-- Proper Join
SELECT *
FROM #LeftTable lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN #RightTable rt ON lt.PolicyRef = rt.PolicyRef AND lt.RunID = rt.RunID

-- Broken Join (eliminates Pol1 from LeftTable)
SELECT *
FROM #LeftTable lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN #RightTable rt ON lt.PolicyRef = rt.PolicyRef
WHERE lt.RunID = rt.RunID OR rt.runid IS NULL

DROP TABLE #LeftTable
DROP TABLE #RightTable
```

I would expect the two queries to return the same thing, but the pol1 row is eliminated in query 2. I assume this is because there is a record for pol1 where the RunID is not the RunID we need. But I don't see why that should eliminate the row.

Comment: If you use the WHERE clause, you will notice that the filter happens after the tables are joined. Please check my answer and accept answer if right.

Comment: With LEFT JOIN you need to have conditions in "ON" clause, not "WHERE" clause, it is just a rule to have all data from "LEFT" table.

Comment: Hi. You don't understand left join on. It returns inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Also this is an easily found faq.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Left Join losing rows after filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750464/sql-left-join-losing-rows-after-filtering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM #LeftTable lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN #RightTable rt ON lt.PolicyRef = rt.PolicyRef
WHERE lt.RunID = rt.RunID OR rt.runid IS NULL
```

this part

```
SELECT *
FROM #LeftTable lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN #RightTable rt ON lt.PolicyRef = rt.PolicyRef
```

will give you 3 result:

> 100,'pol1','hi',80,'pol1','celec'
>
> 100,'pol2','hi2',90,'pol2','colorado'
>
> 100,'pol2','hi2',100,'pol2','colorado'

but the where statement want that set of result have the same id, so this is the only possible result:

> **100,'pol2','hi2',100,'pol2','colorado'**

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to write `and` in place of where as shown below

```
-- Broken Join (eliminates Pol1 from LeftTable)
SELECT *
FROM #LeftTable lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN #RightTable rt ON lt.PolicyRef = rt.PolicyRef
AND lt.RunID = rt.RunID OR rt.runid IS NULL
```

Comment: If you use the WHERE clause, you will notice that the filter happens after the tables are joined.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior...
First thing to understand, these are NOT logically equivalent queries... The reason you're seeing the "pol1" row being filtered out in the 2nd query is simple. rt.RunID is neither equal to lt.RunID, nor is it NULL... It has a value of "80" and therefore fails to meet either of the OR conditions.